# Bash script to deploy a mongodb cluster on local machine

Tags: bash, shell, mongodb, unix, configuration

I recently wrote a small script to deploy a [**mongodb**](https://www.mongodb.com/) cluster on a single machine. 
The cluster is composed of :

- 3 configurations server that holds the same informations (they are [**replicas**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) )
- 2 [**shard**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) server wich will store the data
- one [**mongos**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/) which manage connection to the cluster

The script parse a configuration file holding the cluster configuration, 
and then starts the different member in a specific order.

Here is the config file:

```
#config file to store host and port 

#config server list, in folowing format: 
# config=<host>:<port>  
# started with --dbpath /data/configX where 
# X is the position of the server in the list 
config=localhost:27018
config=localhost:27019
config=localhost:27020

#mongos instance in folowing format:
# mongos=<host>:<port> 
mongos=localhost:27017

#shard list in folowinf format: 
# shard=<host>:<port>
# started with --dbpath /data/shardX where 
# X is the position of the shard in the list
shard=localhost:27021
shard=localhost:27022
```

and here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script should be launched on the server where you want the 
# mongos to run. It should be run like this: 
# ./deploy.sh path/to/config.txt

# make sure that mongod, mongos and mongo are linked correctly 
# you can achieved this using the following command: 
# sudo ln -s /path/to/mongo/bin/mongo /bin/mongo

# host:port for config server
CONFIG=()
# host:port for shards
SHARD=()

# text colors
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`

# clear log file
echo "" > log.txt

# ignore empty or comment line 
sed '/^#/d;/^$/d' $1 | 
{
while read -r line
do

    IFS='=' read -a array <<< "$line"
    val="${array[1]}"
    key="${array[0]}"

    if [ "$key" == "config" ]; then
        CONFIG+=("$val")
        echo "mongod config server: $val"
    fi
    if [ "$key" == "mongos" ]; then
        MONGOS="$val"
        echo "mongos instance: $val" 
    fi
    if [ "$key" == "shard" ]; then 
        SHARD+=("$val")
        echo "shard instance: $val"
    fi
done
#start config servers
index=0
for conf in "${CONFIG[@]}"
do
    # ping each host to make sure it's reacheable
    IFS=':' read -a config <<< ${CONFIG[$index]}
        mkdir /data/config$index 
        echo "starting config server $index" 
    mongod --configsvr --port ${config[1]} --dbpath /data/config$index --replSet conf > log.txt&
    index=$(($index + 1))
    sleep 1
done

sleep 10
echo "${green}config servers deployed${reset}" 
# setup the config replica set. Only neccessary on first launch
IFS=':' read -a config0 <<< ${CONFIG[0]}
mongo --host ${config0[0]} --port ${config0[1]} --eval "rs.initiate( { _id: \"conf\", members: [ {_id: 0, host:\"${CONFIG[0]}\"}, {_id: 1, host:\"${CONFIG[1]}\"}, {_id: 2, host:\"${CONFIG[2]}\"} ]})"&

# sleep so a primary shard can be designed among config servers
sleep 15
# get mongos infos
IFS=':' read -a mongos <<< $MONGOS
#start mongos 
mongos --port ${mongos[1]} --configdb "conf/${CONFIG[0]},${CONFIG[1]},${CONFIG[2]}" > log.txt&

echo "${green}mongos instance configured${reset}"

sleep 5
# start each shard and add them to the cluster
shardnb=0
for shard in "${SHARD[@]}"
do
        IFS=':' read -a sh <<< ${SHARD[$shardnb]}
        mkdir /data/shard$shardnb 
        echo "starting shard $shardnb"
    mongod --shardsvr --port ${sh[1]} --dbpath /data/shard$shardnb > log.txt&
        sleep 5
        mongo --host ${mongos[0]} --port ${mongos[1]} --eval "sh.addShard(\"$shard\");"&
    sleep 5
    shardnb=$(($shardnb + 1))
    echo "${green}shard  $shard added${reset}" 
done

# make sure that the sharded cluster has been deployed correctly 
mongo --host ${mongos[0]} --port ${mongos[1]} --eval "sh.status();"
}
```

I use this to quickly deploy a cluster in a docker container in order to run automated integration test. 
As this is one of my first bach script, I'm looking for advises on style / readability !

Comment: Use `$()` instead of backticks, it is the current POSIX standard and is better for several reasons:  Your tput lines should change from `red=`tput setaf 1` to `red=$(tput setaf 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, I agree with Jesse_b that command substitution should use `$()`. There's no reason to use backticks in a bash script that uses arrays (that's to say, you're not particularly aiming for portability with some obscure shell).

### Indentation

I didn't notice until the end of the script that the majority of your code is in a `{...}` block. Indenting that portion of the code more than the braces would have helped.

---

### Reading the config file

Continuing from the previous point, the majority of your code seems to be in the block because of the pipe used for reading the file.

#### Avoid the pipe

You can use **process substitution** to avoid the pipe:

```
while read -r line
do
...
done < <(sed '...' file)
```

This way, you eliminate the pipe and the need to keep most of your code in a subshell. You can also make the comments more friendly by allowing leading spaces:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*#/d;/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

Or:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*\(#.*\)\?$/d'
```

#### Eliminate unnecessary reads and variables

That said, the code for reading the lines seems to be unnecessarily convoluted: a `read` first and then again to split? Why not do it in one op? You also use an array, then immediately proceed to assign the array elements to two named variables and thereafter ignore the array completely. Just set those variables via `read` directly;

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
...
done < <(sed '/^[[:space:]]*\(#.*\)\?$/d' file)
```

Bug, again, later on you split the `value`s read here, because they are all host-port pairs. If so, then do the splitting now, and save them in separate arrays in the first place:

```
declare -a CONFIG_HOSTS CONFIG_PORTS SHARD_HOSTS SHARD_PORTS
while IFS='=:' read -r key host port
do
...
done < <(...)
```

#### Repetitive if statements

Next, the chain of `if`s are so repetitive that I suggest taking out the `echo`s, by making an array out of the labels you print:

```
declare -A key_labels
key_labels["config"]="mongod config server"
key_labels["mongos"]="mongos instance" 
key_labels["shard"]="shard instance"
```

Then, a single `printf` should do. And the block of `if`s also look like they fit the role of a `case` statement. So:

```
printf '%s: %s:%s\n' "${key_labels[$key]}" "$host" "$port"
case key in
config)
    CONFIG_HOST+=("$host")
    CONFIG_PORT+=("$port")
    ;;
mongos)
    MONGOS_HOST="$host"
    MONGOS_PORT="$port"
    ;;
shard)
    SHARD_HOST+=("$host")
    SHARD_PORT+=("$port")
    ;;
esac
```

So, the entire config reading section becomes:

```
declare -a CONFIG_HOSTS CONFIG_PORTS SHARD_HOSTS SHARD_PORTS
declare -A key_labels
key_labels["config"]="mongod config server"
key_labels["mongos"]="mongos instance" 
key_labels["shard"]="shard instance"

while IFS='=:' read -r key host port
do
    printf '%s: %s:%s\n' "${key_labels[$key]}" "$host" "$port"
    case key in
    config)
        CONFIG_HOSTS+=("$host")
        CONFIG_PORTS+=("$port")
        ;;
    mongos)
        MONGOS_HOST="$host"
        MONGOS_PORT="$port"
        ;;
    shard)
        SHARD_HOSTS+=("$host")
        SHARD_PORTS+=("$port")
        ;;
    esac
done < <(sed '/^[[:space:]]*\(#.*\)\?$/d' file)
```

---

## Looping with an index

Here, since you need the indices for creating the directories, you can just ask bash for the indices directly. Instead of:

```
index=0
for conf in "${CONFIG[@]}"
do
...
    index=$(($index + 1))
done
```

Do:

```
for index in "${!CONFIG_HOSTS[@]}"
do    
    mkdir /data/config"$index"
    echo "starting config server $index" 
    mongod --configsvr --port "${CONFIG_PORT[index]}" --dbpath /data/config"$index" --replSet conf > log.txt &
    sleep 1
done
```

Other notes on this block:

- Note how I eliminated the `IFS=: read ...` and replaced `"${config[1]}"` with `"${CONFIG_PORT[index]}"`, which immediately makes the meaning of that variable clearer.
- The indentation was mixed up, both in this and the other loop. Be consistent.
- The `echo "" > log.txt` from earlier was unnecessary, since you use `> log.txt` here, the file will be truncated anyway.
- **You are losing the output from all but the last `mongod` process**, since you use `>` instead of `>>`.
- Always quote your variables.

This index method can be applied to the other loop as well. Also, every instance of `IFS=: read ... <<<"$foo"` can now be eliminated, and the resultant variables replaced with the arrays we created earlier, as shown in point 1 above. So, things like `config0[1]` become `${CONFIG_PORT[0]}`.